# How to display custom attribute to admin product edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes, product-page

I have created a custom product attribute in my install script using `addAttributeGroup()` method.

How to display this attribute on product edit page tabs programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Found the way. I don't need a separate `tab.phtml` file.

this portion of codes already put it in product edit tab

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attrCode, array(
    'group'         => 'Vela Cash On Delivery',
    'input'         => 'boolean',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'label'         => 'Allow Cash On Delivery',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    //'comparable'  => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'  => false,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'unique'        => false
));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento-1.9, Display the custom attribute settings

**Magento Admin Panel** -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add Attribute ->

**Frontend Properties** -> Visible on Product View Page on Front-end -> Yes

Once you can try this method.